# deriving (Show, Eq) with function in data types

Tags: haskell

I have some data types which as one argument I have functions

```
data Event =
   BasketCreated{basket:: Basket}
  | ProductAdded{ basket::Basket, addProductInBasket :: Basket -> String -> Int -> Basket}
  | DiscountAdded{ basket::Basket, addDiscountInBasket :: Basket  -> Int -> Basket }
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

unfortunately since my data type contains functions `deriving (Show, Eq)` is not compiling.

Any idea how can I `deriving (Show)` with functions to be able to print that data type

Comment: How do you plan to print the functions? Do you just want to not show them at all, or print some placeholder strings for the functions?

Comment: I don’t mind not showed

Comment: see: [Why is there no Show instance for functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Show_instance_for_functions)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will keep the ticket open as a reference. If you rather response I will mark the question as answered

Comment: Okay, if it is useful, I post it as answer for other persons reference later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Show` instance for functions. the reason why it cannot be an instance of `Show`, please refers: [Show instance for functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Show_instance_for_functions)

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned in the comments, you cannot derive a `Show` instance if your data type contains functions. The best you can do is to implement the instance yourself. E.g.:

```
instance Show Event where
  show (BasketCreated x)   = "BasketCreated " ++ show x
  show (ProductAdded x _)  = "ProductAdded "  ++ show x
  show (DiscountAdded x _) = "DiscountAdded " ++ show x
```